# Is $x*y=xy+1$ an Abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Given that $$G = \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x*y=xy+1$$
I have to show whether this an is Abelian group or not.

As an Abelian group has to be associative $a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c$, I think that the given example cannot be a group. Here is my shot

Say that $a = 3, b=2 \text{ and } c=4$

so $$a + (bc+1) = (ab+1)+c$$
but $12 \neq 11$, which shows that it cannot be an Abelian group as it is not associative.

Is my reasoning correct in this particular example?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: It doesn’t even have an identity.

Comment: Where does $a + (bc+1) = (ab+1)+c$ come from? As Siong Thye Goh says, you want $a(bc+1)+1 = (ab+1)c + 1$

Comment: @Henry I noticed that I misinterpret the $xy+1$ part, it is false. Siong Thye Goh has given the right answer.

Comment: An easy way to see that this is not a group is to notice that $0*y = 1$ for every $y$. But in a group, if $x*a=x*b$, then $a=b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a(bc+1)+1 = (ab+1)c + 1$$
reduces to
$$a=c.$$

To get counterexample, just pick $a \ne c$.